# Loops with a string and output to unique configurations in C?

Tags: c, string, loops, variables

So I haven't used C in about a year, and the experience I had was starting from 0, no knowledge in computer sciences or anything. Literally started by writing functions like strlen and split whitespaces from scrach, basically creating my own library in plain C.

I now want to use C for the following problem:
I'm designing a game, and have units with 4 values in them. 3 of the sides each have value x/y/z with any possible combinations and the 4th value is the power that is equal to the most repeated symbol (if x = 3; power = 3/ if x/y/z (= 1) power = 1...).
What I want to do it output the number of total units with respetive power 1 2 and 3 in unique counters... How do I go about that?
What I have so far is:

```
char U[] = "111";  

int result;

void P()

   while (strcmp(U, "333") !=0);

        while (char U[0] <= "3");

   char U[0]++;
```

..... and so on for all the values for it to go to 333.

How do I make it count the different power level units, and also is it possible to not only say for example that the total units of power level 2 is 15, but also in what configuration (eg 1/1/3 or x/x/z)?

Excuse my stupid question if there is already a question that's been answered that covers this type of problem, I just have no idea how to word it....

Edit: In fact, what i am looking for is, a function(program? as i do not want to have an input when compiling) that cycles each of the 3 values in a string (1-3) independently storing and outputting the total numbers of unique configurations (1/1/2 2/1/1 1/2/1) as a number, while counting the total number of configurations that contain the same value 1, 2 or 3 times.

Comment: "_What i have so far is:_" how do we have to understand the 'code' after ? this is not C. Note in C `<=` with strings compare pointers rather than their contents, use _strcmp_ to compare their contents

Comment: Also `while` is for loops.  Maybe you are thinking of `if`

Comment: @bruno i mean to compare the value of the string, saying while the string has a value equal of less than 333 it keeps the loop going. Guess i'll have to correct that.

Comment: @stark - i am actually looking for a loop, i think....

Comment: @YeYeeeeee so my remark is correct, usr _strcmp_ for that

Comment: I tried to correct your code, see my answer

Comment: warning you edition to have "strcmp(U, "333"))" is wrong because the body will never allow you to get the string 333 so strcmp will always returns 1 or -1 but never 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I well understand your code

> ```
> char U[] = "111";
>
> void P()
>
>   while (char U[] <= "333");
>
>        while (char U[0] <= "3"
>
>   char U[0]++;
> ```

you want in fact something like :

```
char U[] = "111";

void P()
{
  while (strcmp(U, "333") <= 0)
    while (U[0] <= '3')
       U[0]++;
}
```

Anyway the nested *while* is in useless and you can have just

```
char U[] = "111";

void P()
{
  while (strcmp(U, "333") <= 0)
    U[0]++;
}
```

The value when you will return from *P* will be "411", is that you expect ?

---

Putting all in a program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char U[] = "111";

void P()
{
  while (strcmp(U, "333") <= 0)
    U[0]++;
}

int main()
{
  P();

  puts(U);
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wextra -Wall s.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
411
```

---

Edition from your remark, if I well understand you want a function getting a string of 3 letters and returning the max number of time any letter inside is repeated

can be :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int count(const char * s)
{
  if (s[0] == s[1])
    return (s[0] == s[2]) ? 3 : 2;

  return ((s[0] == s[2]) || (s[1] == s[2])) ? 2 : 1;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  if ((argc != 2) || (strlen(argv[1]) != 3))
    printf("usage: %s <string of 3 characters>", *argv);
  else
    printf("%d\n", count(argv[1]));

  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wall -Wextra s.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out aze
1
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out aaz
2
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out aza
2
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out azz
2
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out aaa
3
```

---

Edit again to do all possibilities with 3 letters among 3 (1, 2 or 3 in the program) :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int count(const char * s)
{
  if (s[0] == s[1])
    return (s[0] == s[2]) ? 3 : 2;

  return ((s[0] == s[2]) || (s[1] == s[2])) ? 2 : 1;
}

int main()
{
  char cnt[4] = { 0 }; /* index 0 not used */
  char s[3];

  for (int i = '1'; i <= '3'; ++i) {
    s[0] = i;
    for (int j = '1'; j <= '3'; ++j) {
      s[1] = j;
      for (int k = '1'; k <= '3'; ++k) {
        s[2] = k;
        cnt[count(s)] += 1;
      }
    }
  }

  printf("number of possibilities to have no repetition (count == 1) : %d\n", cnt[1]);
  printf("number of possibilities to have 2 letters equals (count == 2) : %d\n", cnt[2]);
  printf("number of possibilities to have all letters equals (count == 3) : %d\n", cnt[3]);

  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wall -Wextra s.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
number of possibilities to have no repetition (count == 1) : 6
number of possibilities to have 2 letters equals (count == 2) : 18
number of possibilities to have all letters equals (count == 3) : 3
```

Comment: I'm trying to correct it at the moment based on what you said.

Comment: But the outcome i expect should never surpass 333, as each number 1/2/3 is just meant to replace x/y/z. And i want to output the number of all 1/1/2; 1/1/3; 1/2/1.... and then assign a value 1 2 or 3, to the total number with that many repetitions of the same letter(x/y/z or in the current case 1/2/3). For example if we took, x/x/z, x/x/y and x/y/z we would have 1 units with power value 1, and 2 units with power value 2.... I believe that my English is behind the hard explanation of all this....

Comment: `while (char U[] <= "333")` loops even when U is "333" so this is not compatible with "i expect should never surpass 333", else must be `<` rather than `<=`

Comment: so you want a function getting a string of 3 letters and returning the max number of time any letter inside is repeated ? so the result is 3 or 2 or 1 ?

Comment: Yes. I do realize a function is not needed but i just wanted to make my brain move a bit.... We are sure that the 3 value units are only 3 because we can have only x/x/x y/y/y and z/z/z...... Just wanted to figure out how to do it.....

Comment: I have finally managed to phrase it the correct way in my initial question(see at the bottom). Thank you a lot for your help, and i hope i didn't waste your time!

Comment: Thank you, exactly as you have shown, but is it possible instead of having to specify for what string of characters you want it to compile, for it to cycle through all of those and have the same correct output as your example given above?

Comment: Thank you again, and thank you for your time, by looking at your code i actually understand that there was syntax that i have never heard of before to be able to do this in the way that you have shown above. Thank you!